# PrimeFaces Editor not updating value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, confirm-dialog

I have this editor.xhtml where I have editor and a bunch of buttons and confirmdialogs for said buttons. All of this can be used in dialogs in my web application.

editor.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

        <p:confirmDialog widgetVar="saveDialog" appendTo="@(body)" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"
                          message="Do you want to save the content?" icon="ui-icon-disk" severity="info" closable="true" >
            <p:commandButton value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" action="#{customEditorBean.save}" oncomplete="PF('saveDialog').hide()"  />
            <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="PF('saveDialog').hide()" />
        </p:confirmDialog>

        <h:form>
            <span id="editorWidgetVarId">
                <p:editor widgetVar="editorWidget" onchange="rc()" value="#{customEditorBean.sisalto}" width="600" maxlength="8000" />
            </span>
            <p:remoteCommand delay="700" name="rc" actionListener="#{customEditorBean.noticeChange}" process="@this" update="saveButton"/>

            <p:commandButton id="saveButton"  onclick="PF('saveDialog').show()" value="Save" rendered="#{customEditorBean.canSave}"
            disabled="#{!customEditorBean.saveEnabled}" type="button">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

The CustomEditorBean has a save method which is called. That method works correclty since it was working before I added the confirmDialog to this editor.xhtml. Now, if I write something on the editor, the value of the editor is not updated in the backing bean. So when I save, it will just save the old value of the editor, not the value I just wrote in the editor before clicking Save button. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve it...

The reason for the problem: saveButton that opens the dialog was of type="button". When changed to "submit" the saving worked in the dialog.

Now, could someone tell me WHY ON EARTH IS THE TYPE BUTTON NOT WORKING IN THIS CASE!? I wasted a whole day for this.

Comment: p:commandButton does not support to pass values with get requests only submit is supported. There is no need to define the type, just leave it out. Submit is used by default.

Comment: Thank you so much.